# Reusable web page elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simple web page that will be a kind of "App Store" which will show users a list of software they have available to download. I am limited in what I can use since this will be a SharePoint site so I am keeping it restricted to strictly HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Since we will be getting new software approved regularly, the site will need to be updated with new items which means copying and pasting code than adding the new software information.

Does anybody have any suggestions for re-usability? Any prior projects where you kind of automated a web page in this way? I am very open to suggestions.

P.S I am not a web dev, please go easy on my code.

I have the basic mock up of the site where I use grids to display "cards". Each grid contains multiple grids which have unique elements.

HTML

```
    <main class="grid">
        <article>
            <img src="Assets/bananatag.png" alt="Sample Photo">
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Bananatag</h3>
                <p>Bananatag is an email tracking software launched in 2011. 
                    It notifies users whether the emails sent are successfully delivered and opened. 
                    Bananatag is used in email marketing where mass emails are sent to millions of 
                    targeted customers are response awaited.
                </p>
                <button onclick="alerts()">Request Software</button>
                <!-- <button onclick="requestPOST" id="APIPOST"> Request Software</button> -->
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
                <img src="Assets/avaya.png" alt="Sample Photo">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Avaya Equinox</h3>
                    <p>Avaya Equinox for Windows turns your Windows PC into a powerful communications and collaboration 
                        system that can work in conjunction with your Avaya deskphone or enable you 
                        to work without compromise from anywhere. It provides SIP-based Voice-over-IP, IM/presence, web 
                        conferencing and point-to-point and multiparty video and easy to use 
                        contact centric workflows with contextual controls.
                    </p>
                    <button onclick="GET()"> Request Software</button>
                </div>
        </article>
```

CSS

```
.stack{
    padding: 20em;
    overflow: auto;
}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 1em;
    align-items: stretch;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 1em;
}
/*nested*/
.grid > article{
    display: grid;
    background: #eee;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 20% 80%);
    grid-auto-rows: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgbs(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 1em;

}
.grid > article img{
    max-width: 75%;
    min-width: 70%;
    border: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgbs(0,0,0,0.3);
    grid-auto-rows: 70px;
}
.text{
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
.text > button{
    background: rgb(93, 84, 84);
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: _"means copying and pasting code than adding the new software information"_. If you store your item information into a single point, like a json file, you could just read that in and have js populate your cards. Then you could just update the json file instead of continually building the html

Comment: Thats an awesome suggestion @PatrickEvans! That might be tricky with storing images but Im sure I can figure that out. So is it possible to create a new card every time a new information is added? That's kind of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an article factory:

```
  function createObject() {
    var result = document.createElement("article");
    result.innerHTML = "<img><div class=\"text\"><h3></h3><p></p><button>Request Software</button></div>";
    return result;
  }
```

Then you can add contents to prefabricated objects with this function

```
  function setObject(imgsrc,h3,p,onclick) {
    this.querySelector("img").src = imgsrc;
    this.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = h3;
    this.querySelector("p").innerHTML = p;
    this.querySelector("button").onclick = onclick;
  }
```

And use it like this:

```
<div id="contents"></div>

<script>
  var obj = createObject(); // later you can deep copy it, or just create a new object
  setObject.call(obj, "img.jpg", "Test object", "Description", ()=>alert('test'));
  contents.appendChild(obj);
</script>
```

Comment: Wow this is more than I ever expected. Thank you for this Jan! I am new to JavaScript so this is super helpful to me.